# Temaplate Routes Not Working

Tags: ee3, template-routes

According to EE3 documentation:

```
/name/{first_name}/{last_name}
```

with Require All Segments set to no should match

```
/name/Enrico/Fermi

/name/Enrico

/name/III

/name
```

I am trying to use a template route to find a segment_1 parameter (such as a n language site /es/), so that my normal template is loaded at url:

```
/group/template_variable
```

and my language version is:

```
/es/group/template_variable
```

I created the route as follows:

```
/es/group/{template_variable}
```

and i have "reuaire all segments" set to NO.

currently, /es/group/example will match that route, and find the template correctly, but /es/group/ loads nothing (which it should still match per the EE documentation)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for Template Routes](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/template_routes.html) is pretty lamentable, so not a surprise you are having difficulties.

Each template can have only one route to it, and equally each route definition can only link to a single specific template.

It is not clear from your question whether you plan to link all routes of form `/es/group/something` to the same template.  If you do, you need to generalise the route definition to accept 'anything' in the third segment.  Something like:

```
/es/group/{alpha_dash}
```

`{alpha_dash}` is one of the constructs you can use in a route to tell EE what to accept in a segment (in this case `alphabetic characters, 0 through 9, underscore, and dash`).

With this rule anything routing to `/group/template_variable` would be unaffected, but the `/es/` prefixed routes would only go to the template you put the route next to in the CP.

If you want a route to go to a specific (different) template depending on what is in segment 3 you'd need a different route instruction for each template - one for each template.  So something like

route `/es/group/dogs` -> to the spanish dogs template

route `/es/group/cats` -> to the spanish cats template

As before, the /group/cats template etc. should continue to work fine with this route in place.

If you have multiple languages you can generalise these rules by replacing the `/es/` with a more general rule for that segment.  If all of the language flags are two letter, and you have no two-letter template groups something like this might work:

`/{max_length[2]}/dogs` -> routes all URLs of form /xx/dogs to /dogs

HTH

Comment: Still giving me an issue. problem is, I need /es/group/ to go to the page, as well as /es/group/dogs to go to the page such that (assuming the page were about pets) I can specify a default value if no pet is given, or if /dogs is in the url, I can load data specific to dogs.

Comment: Oh - OK.  Well there are two ways you could try to get a solution.  One is to put in once of these fiendish multi-rule routes - something like:

Comment: `{tag:max_length[2]|group}/{tag2:group}` - with 'segments required' set to no.  This (should) route anything with the form /group/ or /xx/group.  If you have several 'groups' just add these as further pipe elements to each segment - e.g `{tag:max_length[2]|cats|dogs}/{tag2:cats|dogs}` - but to be honest these complex rules never seem that good - so there is another solution you could try... (next comment)

Comment: If you don't have that many use cases, the alternative is to skip Template Routes completely, and do the same thing using either `layout` or `embed`.  What you do is create all the templates that you might need (so create a template group called 'es' and put a template called 'group' within etc.).  Then fill these templates with a layout or embed instruction that populates them with the template you want to use.  I use `stash:embed` for this - with templates having the following one-line entry: `{stash:embed:target_template_name process="start"}` - as a solution it is a bit crude, but works.